# How to aggregate on a left join in a Postgres CTE?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

In this CTE, each row in `mytable` can have 0 or many rows joined to it in `jointable`. I'm trying to returning an `array_agg` of the `jointable`'s `value` column in this query, but I get an error saying I can't have an aggregate in a `RETURNING`.

```
WITH updated as(
    UPDATE mytable SET status = 'A'
FROM
  (
    SELECT id FROM mytable
    WHERE status = 'B'
    ORDER BY mycolumn
    LIMIT 100
    FOR UPDATE
  ) sub
  LEFT JOIN jointable j USING (id)
WHERE mytable.id = sub.id
GROUP BY (mytable.id)
RETURNING mytable.id, array_agg(j.value)
)
select *
from updated
ORDER BY mycolumn
```

Comment: Can you post sample input for each table and what you want the desired end state to be?  I'm not sure I follow what you want to happen; it sounds like you want a query result with an array in the output, but the synax above implies you are trying to change the status in `mytable`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a `GROUP BY` clause in an `UPDATE` statement. Also, the `UPDATE` won't necessarily visit *all* matching rows in the joined table, so it wouldn't be able to return then anyway.

You will have to join `jointable` again in the outer query to get the desired result.